# Apache Flink: Map function over values of a KeyedStream, without losing keyed state

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a keyed stream:

```java
KeyedStream<String, Data> keyed = 
env.addSource(...)
   .map(new Parser())
   .keyBy(i -> i.key)
```

I want to run a state-full process function on my stream; but the `process` will return a normal un-keyed stream that cause losing `KeyedStream` and force my to call `keyBy` again:

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Data> unkeyed = keyed.process(new Function)
KeyedStream<String, Data> keyedAgain = keyed.keyBy(i -> i.key)
```

- Is there any way to call a map function over values on a `KeyedStream`?
- How I can run a state-full function without using a low-level API like `ProcessFunction` that cause unwanted cost: a new sub-task at runtime, plus re-shuffeling my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `RichMapFunction` or a `RichFlatmapFunction` and have access to Flink's managed state mechanisms. What you'll be missing, compared to a `ProcessFunction`, is timers.

See the example [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state).

Comment: And one more question: in the case of multiple `keyBy`, is there a chance of optimization? A way to grouping multiple processes in the same slot and remove the shuffling overhead?

Comment: But `KeyedStream.map` returns `SingleOutputStreamOperator` not `KeyedStream`. Do we have to rekey the resulting stream again?

Comment: You can apply the map first, and then the keyBy.